# Texture Atlas Tool message ” Not All Objects Are Visible!”

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I just tried the **Texture Atlas Tool** and love it, but I also have a problem.

I have 3 layers where when I press "StartManualUnwrap", I get an error message saying: **"Not All Objects Are Visible!!!"**

I used unhide all (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to make sure, but it does not help.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

BTW, all objects have UV maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same problem , it´s because of the render layer, it needs to be enabled (the layer the object is in and the render layer have to be  the same) In the render layer tab enable the layer your object is in.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the existing UV Group in the menue by pressing the minus button. Create a new one, and do the procedure. For me this worked